# Realm write / add with dictionaries

Tags: swift, realm

I have the following code:

```
var rawTypeArray = [[String: String]]()
rawTypeArray = NSArray(contentsOfFile: finalPathString) as! [[String: String]]

for eachType: [String: String] in rawTypeArray {
let setType = SetTypes(value: eachType)
    try! realm.write {
       realm.add(setType)
    }
 let all = realm.objects(SetTypes.self)
 print (all)
}
```

the values of the dictionary are not passed to the realm object. 
All the object are initialized with the default values. The dictionary values are ignored, what's wrong?

Comment: Can you please share the definition of your `SetTypes` class, and a representative sample of what `rawTypeArray` contains after you've populated it from the file on disk?

Comment: Hi i got my error, the plist keys of the dictionary are capitalized and the objects names not... anyway thanks.